# Trouble with ImageMagick

Tags: html, macos, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm not that experienced using ImageMagick, so I need some help achieving the following :

- Take an original image (590x300)
- Scale it down (to 354x180)
- Crop it (take just the left-most part of it, so that the final image is 229x180)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out myself! So, here it is (for future reference) :-)

**Take an original image (590x300) :**

Let's call that `original.jpg`.

**Scale it down (to 354x180) :**

```
convert original.jpg -scale 354x180 scaled.jpg
```

**Crop it to 229x180 :**

```
convert scaled.jpg -crop 229x180+0x0 final.jpg
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Or all in just one command :

```
convert original.jpg -scale 354x180 -crop 229x180+0x0 final.jpg
```

---

And that's it! :)